# How to convert array php to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, json, native

I have some problem about parsing array php to javascript array, I use `json_encode` but I get error like

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number

This my code :

```
<?php 
        $b=array();
        $a=array();
        $pat = 0;
        for($i = 0; $i<15;$i++)
        {
            if($pat == 5)
            {
                ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
                array_push($b,$a);
                $a = array();
                $pat = 0;
            }
            ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
            array_push($a,$i.'-1');
            $pat = $pat +1;
        }

    ?>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#example').DataTable( {
            serverSide: true,
            ordering: false,
            searching: false,

            ajax: function ( data, callback ) {
                var out1 = "<?php echo json_encode($b) ?>";
                var out = [["0-1","0-2","0-3","0-4","0-5"],["1-1","1-2","1-3","1-4","1-5"]];

                console.log(out);

                setTimeout( function () {
                    callback( {
                        // draw: data.draw,
                        data: out,
                        recordsTotal: 5000000,
                        recordsFiltered: 5000000
                    } );
                });
            },

        } );
    } );
```

I want result like variable out, what can I do to fix this bug thanks, 
and I'm sorry for my bad English

Comment: Remove the quotes; `json_encode()` outputs a valid JS object literal.

Comment: if i remove json_encode(), var out1 is empty

Comment: Only the quotes. You need `var out1 = <?= json_encode($b) ?>;` With quotes you're dumping the JSON into a string and would have to parse it first, like alyatek suggests, however your JSON already contains double quotes, so you'll get a syntax error: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/poLnxhe3/

Comment: thanks mate, you help me so much

Answer (score 0):

[image: use this code for reference as I mentioned you just need to json_encode for this]

Generally we use rest apis for this kind of work but you can use given code snip in picture for your reference. If you have any specific question, let me know

Comment: Do not post pictures that contain code snippets. Directly write the code. Then, a bit of explanations is missing.

Comment: Sure, but I am using stackoverflow in mobile. Next time I’ll keep it in mind buddy.